# Updating html for specific model instance Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, django

I have a Django template that generates a HTML 'card-like' element for each model instance. Each instance (ie 'post') have a button, when on click, I would like to update a value within that SAME instance.

I have been able to do this within the database, but am struggling with updating the HTML to match. Currently, my solution is updating ALL instances/posts. However, I only want to update it on the instance that had the button click.

Does this make sense? Let me know if it doesn't.
I will attach my code below along with an image demonstration. I did try passing through the event ID and making sure they align up for both the button and paragraph tag, but this seemed to not work.

JS:

```
function signUp(user, event, btn, eventID) {
    var csrftoken = Cookies.get("csrftoken");
    var user_id = user
    var event_id = event

    attendance_count = document.querySelectorAll("#attendance");

    if (btn.classList.contains("event-btn")){
        request_info = "register";
    }
    else if (btn.classList.contains("signUpBtnActive")){
        request_info = "unregister";
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/event/update-attendance/",
        data: {
            user_id: user_id,
            event_id: event_id,
            request_info: request_info,
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken
        },
    }).done(function(response){
        if (attendance_count){
            attendance_count.forEach(element => {
                event_id = element.getAttribute("event-instance");
                if (event_id == eventID){
                    element.innerHTML = response;
                }
            })
        }
    });

}
```

My view:

```
def updateAttendanceView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST.get("user_id");
        event_id = request.POST.get("event_id");
        request_info = request.POST.get("request_info");
    
        user = User.objects.all().filter(id=user_id)
        event = EventPost.objects.get(id=event_id)

        if request_info == "register":
            #create record in model
            if not EventAttendees.objects.filter(attendee__in=user, event=event).exists():
                event_attendee_record = 
EventAttendees.objects.create_event_attendee(user, event)
                event_attendee_record.save()
                event.attendance += 1
                event.save()

        elif request_info == "unregister":
            #remove record from model
            record = EventAttendees.objects.filter(attendee__in=user, event=event)
            if record:
                record.delete()
                event.attendance -= 1
                event.save()
                print("200 - Request Success - Record removed successfully")
            else:
                print("500 - Request Failed - Record not found")

    html = '<p class="m-0 attendance-font">'+str(event.attendance)+'</p>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My html template (I have removed the irrelevant stuff)

```
{% for post in event_posts %}
    <div class="card mb-3 event-card border-0">
        <div class="card-body">
             <div class="container p-2">
                   <div class="row">                            
                        <div class="col-auto pe-3">
                            <div class="row"> 
                                <div class="col p-2">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
                                        <i class="bi-people pe-1 fs-5"></i>
                                        <p class="m-0 attendance-font" id="attendance" event-instance={{event.id}}>{{post.attendance}}</p>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                    
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn shadow-none rounded-pill pt-1 pb-1 event-btn" onclick="signUp('{{user.id}}', '{{post.id}}', this, '{{event_id}}')">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

See the below HTML:
[image]

When I click the sign up button on one post (event 6 in this case), the count updates visually for all cards. This is only a frontend issue.

[image]

Comment: maybe first use `console.log()` in `JavaScript` to see in `javascipt console` in browser what you get in variables and which code is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in your HTML - especially these two lines.

```
event-instance={{event.id}}

onclick="signUp('{{user.id}}', '{{post.id}}', this, '{{event_id}}')"
```

It's unclear from what you've provided how `event.id`, or `event_id` are determined.  I suspect they aren't, and they are always matching because they are always blank.

If you are cycling through `post` items and `event` is a foreign key within post, then you may want to use `post.event.id` or `post.event_id` in each case above.

Comment: I must have been tired - I woke up this morning thinking this exact thing! I should in fact have been using 'post.id' in both cases. I would also probably remove the 'eventID' argument from the JS function as am already passing that as 'event'.

Answer (score 1):

Ive cleaned up your code a bit and made sure each card has unique ids. It should fix your problem. Make changes as you require.

In your posts list change the for loop section to this:

```
{% for post in event_posts %}
     <div class="card mb-3 event-card border-0" >
        <div class="card-body" id="event-card-{{post.id}}">
          <div class="row">                            
              <div class="col-auto pe-3">
                  <div class="row"> 
                      <div class="col p-2">
                          <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
                              <i class="bi-people pe-1 fs-5"></i>
                              <p class="m-0 attendance-font">{{post.attendance}}</p>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                          <button type="button" class="btn shadow-none rounded-pill pt-1 pb-1 event-btn" onclick="signUp('{{post.id}}')">Sign Up</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

In your javascript function for making post request, you can try like this.

```
function getCsrfToken(){
    return cookieValue = document.cookie
    .split('; ')
    .find(row => row.startsWith('csrftoken='))
    .split('=')[1];
}

function signUp(post_id){
    const data = {
        // insert your payload here..
    }
    const cookieValue = getCsrfToken();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/event/update-attendance/"+post_id+"/",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': cookieValue},
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: (result)=>{
            if (result.html){
                // update html corresponding to updated card
                $('#event-card-'+post_id).replaceWith(result.html)
            }
        },
        error: (error)=>{
            console.error('There was a problem with the request: ', error);
        }
    })
}
```

Note that on successful post request, you will be simply overwriting the html content of the card being updated.

In your `event update view` you can try the following:

```
@require_POST
def update_event(request, event_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(EventPost, pk=event_id) # Your model
    
    # parse the json data if you are passing in some payload
    json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    # update your instance based on your data above
    # ....
    
    event.save() # save the updates
    event.refresh_from_db() # refresh the instance to reflect the updates

    # render the updated model instance as a string and pass to the json response
    html = render_to_string("events/updated.html", {'post':event})
    return JsonResponse({'html': html})
```

Make sure to create another html template which will be used by the view to render the updated `event post`.

Simply set the content of the `updated.html` or whatever you name it to be. (No need to include html tags or scripts, etc. Its going to inherit from the base)

```
<div class="card-body" id="event-card-{{post.id}}">
    <div class="row">                            
        <div class="col-auto pe-3">
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="col p-2">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
                        <i class="bi-people pe-1 fs-5"></i>
                        <p class="m-0 attendance-font">{{post.attendance}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn shadow-none rounded-pill pt-1 pb-1 event-btn" onclick="signUp('{{post.id}}')">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your existing paths..
    path('event/update-attendance/<str:event_id>/', views.update_event, name='update-event'),
]
```

Finally, make sure these are imported at the top of your views.py

```
from django.http import (
    JsonResponse
)
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
import json
```